# How to find parent row based on unique child rows?

Tags: mysql, yii2

my schema (MySQL, InnoDb):

```
Conversation
------------
id (int)

User
----
id (int)

UserConversation
----------------
user_id (int, FK)
conversation_id (int, FK)
```

Just mapping Users to Conversations (many-to-many).

And now, before I create new Conversations between user1 and user2 I want to check if conversation between exactly this two users already exist in DB.

So I want to select:

- Conversation with User1, User2

but not:

- Conversation with User1, User2, User3
- Conversation with User1
- Conversation with User1, User3
- etc.

Other words: my goal is to prevent create duplicate conversations between group of users. How to achieve this is Yii2 ActiveRecord or pure SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a series of exists / not exists criteria in the `where` clause to determine if a `conversation` is between particular users only. The only drawback is that for each user you need to add a new `exists` criteria:

```
select c.id
from conversation c
where exists (select 1 from userconversations uc where uc.conversation_id=c.id and uc.user_id=1)
      and exists (select 1 from userconversations uc where uc.conversation_id=c.id and uc.user_id=2)
      and not exists (select 1 from userconversations uc where uc.conversation_id=c.id and uc.user_id not in (1,2))
```

Another way would be to compare counts of records:

```
select conversation_id, count(if(user_id in (1,2),1,null)) as in_user, count(*) as all_user
from userconversations uc
group by conversation_id
having in_user=2 and all_user=2
```

This query would not require additional criteria in the `where` clause if you have more than 2 users in the list, but may be slower than the `exists` version because of the conditional counting. You need to test both solutions and see which works better for you.